# Use different class type of view model with multi-flavor app and koin

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, koin

I have an app that has multiple flavors

In the shared code between the flavors I have an Activity and a ViewModel that they all use. One flavor however needs to have a different type of view model that extends the shared view model to add extra functionality that the other flavors do not have.

example:

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {}
```

other flavor that extends the shared viewmodel

```
class FlavorViewModel: SharedViewModel() {}
```

in my app classes for each flavor I initialize the specific view model for that flavor

flavor1 and flavor2 app classes

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModelOf(::SharedViewModel)
}
```

and the other flavor with the extended class

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModelOf(::FlavorViewModel)
}
```

Since the activity code is the same regardless of viewmodel how do I reference different view models (making a copy of the activity and placing it in each flavor just to have a different viewmodel type is not an option because then I have to make any change in each activity flavor).

Typically something like this I would just use an interface but an interface cant inherit a class.

What are my options here?

**Edit**

Like suggested I created an interface that both view models implement like this

```
class FlavorViewModel(...):SharedViewModel(...), ICommonViewModel {
//view model implementation
}
```

declared in koin like this

```
viewModel { FlavorViewModel(get(), get(), get(), get(), get(), get()) } bind ICommonViewModel::class
```

and in my activity I get it by this

```
private val _viewModel: ISharedViewModel by viewModel()
```

but I get an exception from koin saying

```
NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'java.lang.Object'. Check your definitions!
```

pointing to the view model in the activity

Comment: Why can't you use a common interface? Your viewModel implementations can both implement an interface and extend `ViewModel`. You can implement all of the interfaces that you want, just can't extend multiple classes.

Comment: @undermark5 when I say I would use and interface I mean something like `interface IViewModel: ViewModel()` and in the activity I would reference it by IViewModel instead of type specific which is not possible. The FlavorViewModel add an additional dependency to it vs the SharedViewModel

Comment: That still doesn't really answer why you can't create a new arbitrary interface like `interface CommonViewModel` and have `SharedViewModel` and `FlavorViewModel` both implement `CommonViewModel` and  extend `ViewModel` (`class FlavorViewModel: ViewModel(), CommonViewModel {}`)

What are you actually trying to do? When you say flavor, do you mean Android build flavor? Like a shared codebase for a free and paid version of the same app? You can't interchange viewModels like you want without them implementing the same interface, unless you redefine each activity and viewmodel in each source set.

Comment: @undermark5 I believe I did what you suggested but koin cannot find the view model now. See my edit above with the error and what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out based off of this [issue in the koin github repo](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/288) trying to do the same thing

We cant use an interface so I created an abstract class that implements ViewModel

```
abstract class CommonViewModel: ViewModel(){
// abstract functions
}
```

and then my ViewModels implement the abstract class

```
class FlavorViewModel(...):CommonViewModel() {
//view model implementation
}
```

then the koin dsl becomes

```
viewModel { FlavorViewModel(get(), get(), get(), get(), get(), get()) } bind CommonViewModel::class
```

and finally the activity implementation

```
private val _viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModel()
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now, Koin can't bind a viewModel to a non-ViewModel type, therefore you can't use the interface as I suggested, but an abstract class can fill the same role as the interface. Quite frankly, I find that to be slightly annoying, but it does make some sense. On a side note, interface can mean slightly different things depending on the context, it can either mean in code use the `interface` keyword, or it can be used to describe what methods and values are exposed on any given type, that is, the interface that you use to interact with it (the `I` in `GUI` is similar to this usage)